# How to know closing event of sub form in parent form

Tags: forms, ms-access

I have a main form with :

- a table of data (list of pay)
- a button calling a subform (assistant form to create easily a bound of pay for a complete year)

After closing the subform, I have to update the main form data (table view) only if the user click Generate (to avoid data update), ie only if the user generate new payroll.

Is there a way to know if the user cancel or not action in the subform?

Comment: Why would you need to update main form data - do you mean refresh? Is main form bound to same data as subform? How would user do 'cancel or not action'? What needs to 'know' if user did 'cancel or not action' - main form? Generate is a custom button on main form? - edit question to show code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you NOT really talking about a form + sub form.

There are two ways to do this:

First, you can open the 2nd child form as acDialog (not modal - very big difference).

So, your main form code can do this:

```
Dim strF    As String
strF = "frmChildForm"

DoCmd.OpenForm strF, , , , , acDialog
' CODE WILL HALT and wait for above form to be closed

' code here continues
' can even update data on this main form from that child form.

If CurrentProject.AllForms(strF).IsLoaded Then
   ' user hit ok - or your save button
   Me.LastChildUpdate = Forms(strF)!LastUpdate

   DoCmd.Close acForm, strF
Else
  ' code goes here - user hit cancel button, or X to close - we assume cancel
End If
```

Now in that other child form, you DO NOT CLOSE when your "done/save/ok" button runs. It simply sets the form's visible property to false

eg:

```
Me.Visible = False
```

So, now our calling code will WAIT until the user is done. If the form is closed, then we assume a user "canceled" that child form.

so, the user can hit X to close, OR the user might hit your close/cancel button. Your close/cancel button thus can close the form. eg this code:

```
docmd.Close acForm,me.name
```

So, now you know if the user canceled (closed) the form. Your "ok/save" button in that form ONLY sets the forms visible=False. That makes the calling code continue, and then you check if the form is open or not - and thus your code can take appropriate action.

However, you don't even have to use the "halt" code trick above.

What you can do in that child form you launch?

You can in the on-open event, or even on-load? You pick up the name of the calling form.

So, you define this in your code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim frmPrevious      As Form


Private Sub Form_Load()

   Set frmPrevious = Screen.ActiveForm

End Sub
```

So, now your save button on this form?
It can call/use/update ANYTHING from the main previous form caller.

So, your save button can now;

```
frmPrevious.Refresh
```

Or

```
frmPrevous!LastName = me.LastName
```

So, you can do "anything" by replacing "me" with frmPrevous, and any operation (such as your custom save button on that 2nd form) can update, call code, refresh, or do anything it wants to operation on the first main calling form.

And you can even call subs/functions in that main form.

So, you could have a public sub in the main form, and in the 2nd form, on the close event do this:

```
 Call frmPrevous.MySubName     ' tell + call code in main form.

 docmd.close acForm,me.name
```

So the above outlines two approaches:

First idea:
You open 2nd form as "acdialog" and the code waits. You either then close the 2nd form (considered a cancel), or you save visible=false and the calling code CONTINUES.

Second idea:
You pick up the previous form in the on-load event. Now your save button can directly update values, controls etc. in "frmPrevious", and then once done, you close the 2nd form in that "ok button" routine.

So, quite much is that in that 2nd form, you can directly update controls and do things to the first calling form with the above 2nd idea.

Or, as noted, you can HALT the calling code that opens the form, wait for user response, and then use the visible=false trick to allow the calling code to continue. Once again, since the 2nd form is still open, you are free to get/grab/take values from that STILL open form, and then when done you thus as a last stop close that 2nd form. So in effect, your 2nd form does NOT close when the user is done - but only visible = false. As noted, this trick only works if you open/call the 2nd form as "acDialog". This is a great idea for say yes/no dialog prompts etc., since then you can upon user selection have the calling code continue, and examine the values in that 2nd form before closing it.

And the last but not least method:

In that 2nd form the code behind your "ok" button can simple update the first form

```
forms!MyFirstForm!LastName  = me.LastName

docmd.close acForm,me.name
```

However, above has the form(s) name hard coded, and frmPrevious trick is thus somewhat better since then you don't hard code the calling forms name, and thus many forms can call + use that same 2nd form.